# Request Timed out with Code

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire, connection-timeout

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608000244a70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.dfdd, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.dfdd.com, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Am getting this response calling MY API.. am using alamofire to call the api.. Is any problem in alamofire or local API

Comment: no not like it will hapen with many scenarios

Comment: How to find the solution to over come this

Comment: for e.g if your network connecttion is low or your data is heavy weight on that time it will occur mostly

Comment: OK..any other thing

Comment: if server takes more time to respond your req at the time it will raise

Comment: may be server retruns the heavy data also on that time it will occur

Comment: OK...thanks to all for ur replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to following solution.

1. Connect with fast internet connection because your request carry heavy data.
2. Set request timeout to session manager

   manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

Comment: use this `timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120` one is option bz if you used your API in main thread it affect another threads also on delay

Comment: set interval for timeoutIntervalForResource  too while getting heavy data.

Comment: @KKRocks is it possible to set in Alamofire manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

Comment: @KKRocks.. In alamofire before calling the api i set the timeoutIntervalFor Request.. but am facing the same problem...here is my code

Comment: func requestDELETEData(urlString:String, parameterToBePassed:inout Dictionary<String,AnyObject>, completion:@escaping (_ resultDictionary:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?, _ error:NSError?) -> ())
    {
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .delete, parameters: parameterToBePassed)
            .responseJSON
            {}}

Answer (score 1):

The main causes of this issue are either:

1. The server is under heavy load, or does not have the resources to be able to respond in a timely fashion
2. The users network connection is slow, and unable to download the response quick enough.

You should check your API & Server logs to look for any potential issues there, ensure there are no errors and that the API is capable of handling your requests as the app scales.

Also, you should add some additional error handling in your application so that if this issue does occur, not only do you handle the case properly and show the user that an error occured (or retry) and also log/report the error so that you can respond to it and investigate.

Sometimes users connections will drop due to loss of mobile signal or other reasons so you need to handle this gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.fdfd.com, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.fdfd.com, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}....            am getting the error in alammofire..how to solve this