# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataPDTask

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, express, watchos

I want to send a dictionary as a JSON to the express API but I keep getting this error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataPDTask

The server cannot be reached for some reason and I do not know why. I have already specified the content type and I have tried so many answers, but nothing has worked. I hope you can help me out.

Here is the relevant swift code

```swift
 func sendSignal(){
    let params: Dictionary=["name":"Hello my name is Student1234!","message":"Hi"]

     guard let url = URL(string:"http://147.46.215.219:8080/addSignal") else{
             print("Failed to send signals!")
             return
         }
         var request = URLRequest(url:url)

         request.httpMethod = "POST"

     // insert data to send into sending body

         do{
             request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
         } catch{
             print(error.localizedDescription)
         }

         request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
         request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Type")

         let session = URLSession.shared
         session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) in
             print("Sending completed!")
             }).resume()

    }
```

Here is my express code:

```
var express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
var cors = require('cors');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());


// connection to interventions_db

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
})

// connections to signals_db

var signalsConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_SIG_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_SIG_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_SIG_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_SIG_DATABASE,
    port: process.env.DB_SIG_PORT
});



app.post('/interventions', function (req, res) {
    const intervention = {
        interventionType: req.body.interventionType,
        place: req.body.place,
        students: req.body.students,
        date: req.body.date,
        time: req.body.time,
        severity: req.body.severity,
        teachers: req.body.teachers
    }

    var q = "INSERT INTO interventions SET ?;";

    connection.query(q, intervention, function (error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(result);
        res.send("Posted to DB");
    })
    console.log("Entry successfully added to the database");
    console.log("POST Request SENT To /INTERVENTIONS");
})

app.get('/posts', function (req, res) {

    var q = "SELECT * FROM interventions;";

    connection.query(q, function (error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
})

// app.post('/addSignal', function (req, res) {

//     console.log("Hello from Here" + req);
//     var signalType = req.body.body
//     var dataObj = {};
//     var q;
//     if (signalType === "heartrate") {
//         q = "INSERT INTO heartrate SET ?;";

//         dataObj = {
//             bpm: req.body.bpm,
//             date: req.body.date,
//             studentId: req.body.studentId
//         }
//         console.log(req.body.signalType);
//         console.log("Here is the data Object " + dataObj);
//     } else if (signalType === "locations") {
//         dataObj = {
//             long: req.body.long,
//             lat: req.body.lat,
//             date: req.body.date,
//             studentId: req.body.studentId
//         }
//     }
//     else if (signalType === "movements") {
//         dataObj = {
//             gravity: req.body.gravity,
//             acceleration: req.body.acceleration,
//             rotation: req.body.rotation,
//             attitude: req.body.attitude,
//             date: req.body.date,
//             studentId: req.body.studentId
//         }
//     }
//     else if (signalType === "audio") {
//         dataObj = {
//             audio: req.body.audio,
//             date: req.body.date,
//             studentId: req.body.studentId
//         }
//     }
//     else {
//         console.log("wrong signal type!")
//     }

//     signalsConnection.query(q, dataObj, function (error, result) {
//         if (error) throw error;
//         console.log(result);
//     })
//     res.status(200).end();
//     console.log("Signal successfully added to the database");
//     console.log("POST Request SENT To /addSignal");

// }
// )

app.post('/addSignal', function (req, res) {
    var parsedBody = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log(parsedBody)
    res.send("Request received")
})

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 8080!");
});
```

Thank you very much. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: did you try this with let session = URLSession(.default) ??

Comment: @AkhileshSharma: You mean instead of let session = URLSession.shared?

Comment: yes that's right.. Seems like there are processes that are running already on you shared session object

Comment: @AkhileshSharma: I have tried your suggestion and have tried this line : let session = URLSession(configuration:.default), just default did not work. But still there is still the timeout. It does not work unfortunately

Comment: Then it seems like the port at which your server is running is not responding back because your backend logic seems to work fine. Is the request reaching to server that is running on port 8080

Comment: @AkhileshSharma: I am sorry, but can you explain it a little bit further? How can you check whether the request can reach port 8080? I still a beginner that's why I still do not understand it clearly

Comment: I have posted some suggestion on the chat. Please let's continue to chat there instead of extended discussion here

Answer (score 0):

Check for two things.

- Default timeout on server-side
- Assign request timeout to your `URLSession` (if possible keep it greater than server timeout)

There is a possibility that your data is heavy and before your server returns the response timeout might be happening.

Comment: I just need to find out what the default timeout of the server is and set a higher timeout for the URLSession? But I do not set a timeout on the server-side. Is it what you mean? 
And this can solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know what your server-side set up looks like apart from the code you have posted. But technically there should be timeout on both server side as well as client side. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564563/7420795